# div width transition, make 2nd div use remaining horizontal space

Tags: css

I have three divs taking up a third of the horizontal space. When I hover over one of them, it transitions to two thirds of the horizontal space. When I hover over that div, I want the remaining two divs two shrink to one sixth each. So basically I want them to fill whatever horizontal space is left when the first div expands.

Like so:
[---div1---][---div2---][---div3---]
on hover:
[---------div1---------][div2][div3]

Is this possible with css?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Some HTML, attempted CSS? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a transition I think you would need to use floats as follows:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kaqE/2/)

**HTML**

1
    2
    3

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

figure div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    border:1px solid red;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

figure:hover div {
    width:16.5%;
}

figure div:hover {
    width: 66.66%;
```

}

Comment: yeah that's the last piece of the puzzle! you made my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `table` display:

```html
<figure>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</figure>
```

```css
figure {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

figure div {
    display: table-cell;
}

figure div:hover {
    width: 66.66%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8kaqE/).

Here the fixed `table-layout` property ensures that all cells are the same width; as we have 3 columns, in specifying a width of 66.66% (4/6th) on hover means that our two other `div` elements shrink to 16.66% width - 1/6th.

Comment: that works pretty much perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: Does it transition? I couldn't get that to work but perhaps I missed something.